# What happens to a pass vault when the GPG key expires?

Tags: password-management, gnupg

Say I were to use the Linux tool `pass` as my password manager and the corresponding GPG key were to expire. Would I still be able to get in?

Comment: Could I ask a mod to restore the other guys' answer? It didn't technically answer my question, but it was great background information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes*, you would still be able to get in. Expiring a key tells people not to use it anymore, but anything already encrypted with the public key can still be decrypted with the private key.

A GPG key's expiration can also be [extended at any time](https://superuser.com/q/813421) unless it's been revoked.

<sub>*The software may prevent using expired or revoked keys, but if so this limitation isn't necessary and could be removed.</sub>

Comment: I get the feeling that the gpg-agent would deny any attempts to use expired keys. But it is open source, and could be modified to simply ignore that aspect? Is that what you mean by 'removed'?

Comment: @DeepDeadpool Correct. If you can access the private key you can still do all the cryptography. And as I noted, expired keys can have their expiration extended, only revoked keys might be an issue.